# can't add subview to UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to create a horizontal scroll view which has a UILabel as elements, by doing the following in viewDidLoad:

```
for(int index=0; index < [self.category count]; index++)
    {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.text = [self.category objectAtIndex:index];
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(100,9999);
        CGSize expectedLabelSize = [[self.category objectAtIndex:index] sizeWithFont:label.font                        
                                      constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                                          lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; 
        label.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset, 0, expectedLabelSize.width, 40);

        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth+xOffset,110);
        [self.scrollView addSubview:label];

        xOffset += 170;
    }
```

However, I can't see anything when I run the app in the simulator, what am I missing here? Pretty sure that the UIScrollView is connected via the IBOutlet and I know that the text exists as I tried printing that out via NSLog

UPDATE:
Also how do I check which UILabel is clicked? I wanted to know this as well..

Comment: yea.. I just released the label after adding it to the subview.so I need to autoresizingMask the scrollView?

Comment: your autoresizingMask actually worked

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're positioning the labels with a frame you should also set `autoresizingMask` to make sure if you position based on a portrait layout but are testing the app in landscape, your labels don't get auto-positioned outside the new bounds. Also, make sure to `autorelease` those labels or else you'll be leaking memory.

Comment: A `UIButton` may have different default settings to a `UILabel`. Make sure you have set `hidden` to `NO`, set the `frame` properly, set `autoresizingMask` properly, and if you're using a custom button it has no image by default so it appears as invisible. If you want a default button appearance you need to call `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];`

Answer (score 1):

I think you did'nt initialize xOffset=0 before running for loop. so that it is taking a garbage value and then executing  xOffset += 170; instruction.

so please initialize  xOffset=0;

Comment: I actually did, just didn't shpw it here

Answer (score 0):

Your `expectedLabelSize` calculation seems to adjust the `height`, leaving the `width` at 100. When you set the `frame` of your `UILabel` you are just using this width.